# What's the best way to add a utility sink drain to this current setup?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, laundry

**Code:** New Jersey

I'm looking to add a utility sink in the basement and am looking for the best way to modify this drainage system to include the utility sink drain.

[image]

My thoughts are to take the current sanitary tee connecting the right washer drain and replace it with a double sanitary tee, routing a 1.5" line up to the vent above similar to how the right washer drain is already set up. My question is will adding a double tee here be okay and not cause any backflow into the utility sink drain system? Is there another way I should be looking at this?

Comment: Without looking up any oddities of NJ code, I'd just put a Wye in "Left washer drain" and either put Left washer or the Utility sink in the side of the Wye, with the other one out the end of the wye. Existing vent should be fine, or you could Tee one up if you liked.

Comment: I considered that but the left washer runs about 40 inches from ground whereas the right runs 18 which is much closer to the  approximate height of a sink drain

Comment: Clearly not where they enter the drain pipe - there isn't 22 inches vertically between the sanitary tees. Might be 6" Possibly the top of the standpipes, but the top of the standpipes isn't what counts, here.

Comment: Depending on the level required for the sink P-trap, you could just use the existing leg of the washer drain, and drain the washer into the sink.